Does the iPhone 13 "oversharpen" photos (still)?
I'm trying to decide between purchasing an iPhone 13 and an iPhone 14 (for about 100€ more).  I know they're relatively similar, although the 14 has 1.5 times the amount of RAM.
One thing that is pushing me towards the 14 is that I've read that the 13 "oversharpens" photos, to the point that it's neither accurate nor pleasing.  Is this true in your experience?  The reports I read were a couple of years old -- has this been fixed in the interim?

I would say it's likely the system camera software doing the computation that "enhances" the photos.
